# Adding Widgets to Reactor Theme (based on Foundation 4)

Tags: widgets

How do I change the footer area to have three widget areas?

The Reactor Theme has one footer widget area.  It separates into three columns if more than one widget is added but I find that difficult to balance up with more than three widgets being used.  So, I tried to change it to three widget areas in the footer.

I have done this before but not in a theme that spreads itself out in the way that Reactor does with all those functions, hooks, actions and stuff.  Anyway, I had a go at changing the code in two files and I have put that here:

http://pastebin.com/MA4nrPBq

I want to get three footer widgets in my admin area but not on my page.  I think I have the right code to edit but how do I edit the code to move this on?

Thanks

Martin

Here's the code I am trying:

```
//In sidebars.php

        if ( in_array( 'footer', $sidebars[0] ) ) {
                $footer  = '<div id="%1$s" class="widget top-bar-widget ';
                $footer .= 'large-' . reactor_get_widget_columns('sidebar-footer-01'); //Added -01
                $footer .= ' columns %2$s">';
                register_sidebar( array(
                        'name'          => __('Footer 01', 'reactor'), //Added 01
                        'id'            => 'sidebar-footer-01', //Added -01
                        'description'   => 'Footer widget area',
                        'class'         => '',
                        'before_widget' => $footer,
                        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
                        'before_title'  => '<h4 class="widget-title">',
                        'after_title'   => '</h4>',
                ) );
        }
        if ( in_array( 'footer', $sidebars[0] ) ) {
                $footer  = '<div id="%1$s" class="widget top-bar-widget ';
                $footer .= 'large-' . reactor_get_widget_columns('sidebar-footer-02'); //Added -02
                $footer .= ' columns %2$s">';
                register_sidebar( array(
                        'name'          => __('Footer 02', 'reactor'), //Added 02
                        'id'            => 'sidebar-footer-02', //Added -02
                        'description'   => 'Footer widget area',
                        'class'         => '',
                        'before_widget' => $footer,
                        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
                        'before_title'  => '<h4 class="widget-title">',
                        'after_title'   => '</h4>',
                ) );
        }
//The above code is just a copy of Reactor code.  I just added the 01, 02 and did it 4 times.

//In sidebar-footer.php

                <?php if ( is_active_sidebar('sidebar-footer') ) : ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="<?php reactor_columns( 12 ); ?>">
                    <div id="sidebar-footer" class="sidebar" role="complementary">
                      <?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-footer-01'); ?> //Added -01
                      <?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-footer-02'); ?> //Added line
                      <?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-footer-03'); ?> //Added line
                    </div><!-- #sidebar-footer -->
                </div><!--.columns -->  
            </div><!-- .row -->
                <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I changed the code a bit more (and edited the past bin) and now I get the widget areas in the dashboard and on the page.

Comment: Please **edit your question** and include your relevant code inline, rather than linking to a third-party site.

Comment: I added my code, sorry about that.  I don't want my code written for me.  I mostly want to know how to go about it.  I can see that I will have to change classes and some other elements but it's the getting the widget areas in that I am interested in.  I can see that Reactor is clever because it divides the footer into columns according to the number of widgets you add.

Comment: Please edit your question to be *a question*.  "I get three footer widgets in my admin area but not on my page", is a statement not a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note in the code you gave for sidebar-footer.php

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar('sidebar-footer') ) : ?>
```

...is always going to return false since that no longer exists.

Since this is a custom theme you can probably just comment out or remove that line and it's endif pair since I trust you always want the markup to output even if the 3 sidebar areas are empty.

Alternatively:

```
 <?php if ( ( is_active_sidebar('sidebar-footer-01') || ( is_active_sidebar('sidebar-footer-02') || ( is_active_sidebar('sidebar-footer-03') ) ) : ?>
     <div class="row">
         <div class="<?php reactor_columns( 12 ); ?>">
             <div id="sidebar-footer" class="sidebar" role="complementary">
               <?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-footer-01'); ?> //Added -01
               <?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-footer-02'); ?> //Added line
               <?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-footer-03'); ?> //Added line
             </div><!-- #sidebar-footer -->
         </div><!--.columns -->  
     </div><!-- .row -->
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: that is really helpful.  Thank you for adding that code, it helps me a lot.  I think it might be missing a couple of closing brackets though.